# CakePHP 1.3 - Calling requestAction() with router-created URL from a shell causes "Missing Controller" error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a CakePHP 1.3 shell that requires the use of requestAction() to generate HTML from a separate controller. The URL for that call is generated using:

```
$url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => $action_str));
$data = array('url' => array('ext' => 'json'), 
              'return' => 'return',
              'pass' => array('an_id_str' => $an_id));
```

$action_str, 'an_id_str', and $an_id are the only things in my code that change between calls, and requestAction() is called as such:

```
$this->requestAction($url, $data);
```

Note: since $action_str can change for each call, it generates the new $url for each individual requestAction() call.

The first time the requestAction() call is made, it works great. The second time I call requestAction(), it throws the following error:

```
"Error: Missing Controller 'c:\...\cake\console'"
```

Any ideas what might be causing the router to mess this up, and how I can fix it?

One note - this actually happens in a couple different shells that use similar functionality.

Comment: I'm a little confused how the first and second time you call the function are different. Are you calling them under the exact same scenario or is the call dependent on some logic? My first thought is that URL rewriting is messing you up somehow. Can you provide more details about what you're calling exactly?

Comment: The only difference is that the action sometimes is different, and the data supplied to the call is different. $this->requestAction($url, $data); where $url is the Router provided URL and $data is an array('url' => array('ext' => 'json'),
       'return' => 'return',
       'pass' => array('an_id_str' => $an_id))

Comment: it calls a controller/action at the specified URL which generates files for export and emails the files to a given user.

Comment: Nobody has encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct fix for this issue is that in my $url array

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => $action_str));
```

I needed to add the 'base' key and set it to false as such:

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => $action_str, 'base' => false));
```

From the docs at http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/router#line-733 :

'There are a few 'special' parameters that can change the final URL string that is generated

- `base` - Set to false to remove the base path from the generated url. If your application is not in the root directory, this can be used to generate urls that are 'cake relative'. cake relative urls are required when using requestAction."'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comment, that clarifies the question you are asking. What you need to do is specify to the `Router::url` call that you wan to use the full URL when building it. To do that, you just put the `true` option on the end.

```
$url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'trial'), true);
```

Comment: This isn't really helpful... I already know that the URLs that get generated are bad (and I stated as such a bunch of times in my post), in fact that's the problem. The issue only happens after my first call to requestAction(), so something in Cake is breaking functionality during that call.

Comment: @Derek, I now understand what you were asking. I have updated my answer. I also tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: voting this up since it pointed me in the right direction, however this did not fix it. see my answer for details